# Use Kafka connect with AWS documentDB

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm trying to use AWS DocumentDB as a sink for storing data received from Kafka and was wondering if the MongoDB Kafka connector works with DocumentDB as its documentation mentions that it is compatible with MongoDB drivers.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/

https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/

If not this connector what is the alternate way other than building a custom kafka connect?

Comment: What specific errors do you get when you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MongoDB Kafka connector  with DocumentDB for source as well Sink.
Kafka Connector worker(with Mongodb Kafka connector) can be run in distributed mode using containers as well as EC2 hosts.

You can refer blog here which has step by step details
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-data-with-amazon-documentdb-and-amazon-msk-using-a-kafka-connector/